# c++ iomanip table formatting

Tags: c++, cout, iomanip

I'm in trouble with `iomanip`. I think a simplified code can explain everything better than words.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

struct Dog {
  std::string name;
  int age;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Dog dog) {
  return os << dog.name << ", " << dog.age << "yo";
}

int main() {
  Dog dog;
  dog.name = "linus";
  dog.age = 10;

  std::cout
    << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::setfill(' ') << "INFO"
    << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::setfill(' ') << "AVAILABLE" << std::endl;

  std::cout
    << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::setfill(' ') << dog
    << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::setfill(' ') << "yes";

  std::cin.get();
}
```

I would print a well formatted table, but my output is bad aligned. In simple words when I `cout` my dog, `setw` and `setfill` works only on dog.name (because of the nature of `operator<<`) and the result is something like

```
INFO                AVAILABLE
linus               , 10yoyes
```

instead of

```
INFO                AVAILABLE
linus, 10 yo        yes
```

Obviously I could modify `operator<<`, appending just one `string` to `os` but in my real case I have to change tons of complex definitions (and I prefer avoiding such changes! :D)

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setw` manipulator sets the field width of the *next* output which in this case is `dog.name`. There's really no way around it if you want to use the stream directly in the overloaded function.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Dog dog) {
  std::string output = 
      dog.name + std::string(", ") + std::to_string(dog.age) 
      + std::string("yo");
  return os << output;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).